# How to copy a Store that has no model

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have the following store:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Status', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '...'
    },
    pageSize: 9999
});
```

The store has no model, and gets the fields from the `metaData` property send from the server.
How do I create a new copy of this store? All examples I found for copying a store need a model to work.

Comment: chk [reconfigure](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#reconfigure-grid)

Comment: these stores have a model, I don't see how this could be usefull

Comment: Do you have any possibility to touch server code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every store in Ext4 has a model. If you don't specify one, it will be created implicitly, so you can always access it with: `myStore.model`. That means you can use the examples you've found with your store.

Comment: a implicit model is only created if the `field` property of the model is not empty. but with setting it to `[]` the store creates an implicit model and the fields get filled by the server. this will do it.